# AndroidStudio 3.2 test configuration does not work

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio-3.2

After migrating to AS 3.2 android JUnit test run configuration does not work, all types "All in directory",
"All in package" etc.
I mean it does work, but always claims that:

```
0 test classes found in package '<default package>'

Process finished with exit code 254
Empty test suite.
```

using `./gradlew test` triggers every test

and every single test can be run by AS using that green play button inside editor (for class or single method)

[image]

but not for package, module etc.

How to fix that ?

many thanks

Wojtek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Android Studio 3.2.1

So just update AS to newest version and the problem disappears

Answer (score 0):

Declare your test classes as public

Comment: not even close to solution, that is kotlin, classes are public by default